# What is the Full-Text Search Equivalent of LIKE '%'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I am using the FTS option of sql server 2008.  In my queries, I would like to pass in a wildcard search.

In std sql, I have this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Person 
WHERE Lastname like '%';  -- this returns all persons
```

Using FTS, I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Person 
 WHERE contains(*, '"*"')  -- this return no rows.
```

The reason I have contains is because i am passing a parameter to an sp.

For example:

```
exec spMySearch('formsof (inflectional, stuff)')
```

In spMySearch(),  I have this:

```
select * from Person where contains(*, @SearchBy)  -- this is the param of spMySearch
```

Is there an approach you can recommend to getting wildcard searches?  I know there is a performance hit, but it is something I would like to try and get working.

Answer (score 2):

contains('"*"') will return zero records by design.

Is there some reason you need to do that though? Why not just do the query without the parameter if it's empty?

```
IF @SearchBy = '' BEGIN
    SELECT  *
        FROM    Person
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT  *
        FROM    Person
        WHERE   CONTAINS(*, @SearchBy)
END
```